# networkD3 in R shiny not displaying properly in Chrome, Firefox, but does in Safari?

Tags: javascript, css, r, shiny, networkd3

Here is the app code:

```
require(shiny)
require(shinydashboard)
require(igraph)
require(networkD3)

ui = dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Test App"),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(id = "tab",style = "position:fixed;",
                               menuItem("Networks", tabName = "nets", icon=icon("project-diagram"))
  )),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$script(HTML("$('body').addClass('fixed');")),
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName="nets", width=12,
              h2("Networks", align="center"),
              fluidRow(
                box(width = 12 ,title = "Network Display", status="info", solidHeader = TRUE, align="left",height="930px", collapsible=FALSE,
                    div(radioButtons(inputId = "RangeChoice",label = "Choose range of nodes:",
                                           choices = c("Few", "Some", "All"),selected = "Few"),style="display:center-align"),
                    forceNetworkOutput(outputId = "ptNetwork",height = "600px")) # box Network Display
              ) # fluidRow
      ) # tabItem nets
    ) # tabItems
  ) # dashboardBody
) # dashboardPage

server = function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$tab, {
    print(sprintf("%s tab is selected.", input$tab))
    if (input$tab == "nets") {
      # draw network
      output$ptNetwork=renderForceNetwork({
        x = matrix(rnorm(100*100), nrow=100, ncol=100)
        colnames(x) = 1:100
        ig = graph.adjacency(adjmatrix = x, mode="undirected", weighted=TRUE, add.colnames = list(attr="name"))
        mets=sample(V(ig)$name, 10)
        zmets=sample(V(ig)$name, 50)
        if ( input$RangeChoice == "Few"){
          e = delete.vertices(ig, v=V(ig)$name[-which(V(ig)$name %in% mets)])
          e = delete.vertices(e, V(e)[degree(e) == 0] )
        }else if(input$RangeChoice == "Some"){
          e = delete.vertices(ig, v=V(ig)$name[-which(V(ig)$name %in% zmets)])
          e = delete.vertices(e, V(e)[degree(e) == 0] )
        }else if(input$RangeChoice == "All"){
          e = ig
        }else{
          print("No Range Selected")
        }
        # assign groups and make ColourScale
        node_first = V(e)$name  %in% mets
        node_second = V(e)$name  %in% zmets
        node_both = node_first & node_second
        group=rep("Neither",length(V(e)$name))
        for (l in 1:length(V(e)$name)) {
          if (node_both[l]) { group[l] = "Both" } else if (node_first[l]) { group[l] = "First" } else if (node_second[l]) { group[l] = "Second" } else { group[l] = "Neither" }
        }
        names(group)=V(e)$name
        ColourScale <- 'd3.scaleOrdinal().domain(["First", "Second", "Both","Neither"]).range(["7554A3", "96C93C", "ECB602","#d3d3d3"]);'
        borderColor = rep("#d3d3d3",length(V(e)$name))
        #generate networkd3
        net_p=igraph_to_networkD3(e)
        net_p$nodes$group=sapply(as.character(net_p$nodes$name),function(x) group[x])
        net_p$nodes$nodesize=rep(1, length(net_p$nodes$name))
        linkColor_first=net_p$nodes$name[net_p$links$source+1] %in% mets & net_p$nodes$name[net_p$links$target+1] %in% mets
        linkColor_second=net_p$nodes$name[net_p$links$source+1] %in% zmets & net_p$nodes$name[net_p$links$target+1] %in% zmets
        linkColor_both = linkColor_first & linkColor_second
        linkColor = rep("lightgrey", length(linkColor_first))
        for (l in 1:length(linkColor)) {
          if (linkColor_both[l]) {
            linkColor[l] = "ECB602"
          } else if (linkColor_first[l]) {
            linkColor[l] = "7554A3"
          } else if (linkColor_second[l]) {
            linkColor[l] = "96C93C"
          } else {
            linkColor[l] = "lightgrey"
          }
        }
        net_p$links$color=linkColor
        
        ptNetwork=forceNetwork(Nodes = net_p$nodes, charge = -90, fontSize = 20, colourScale = JS(ColourScale),
                               Links = net_p$links,
                               linkColour = net_p$links$color,
                               Nodesize = 'nodesize',
                               Source = 'source', Target = 'target',NodeID = 'name',Group = 'group',Value = "value",zoom = T,
                               opacity = 0.9,
                               legend = T)
        ptNetwork
      })
    }  else {
      print("No tab selected")
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here is the URL of the app pushed to shinyapps.io:
https://lrthistlethwaite.shinyapps.io/Test-App/

If you view in Chrome or Firefox, the node color, edges do not show properly. In Safari, everything plots perfectly. See image below for what it should look like. Note, if you run the code in R console itself, the network plots correctly in the R viewer pane, so it's a shiny / Javascript or CSS bug, not a code bug, most likely?

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug ended up being that all hexidecimals specified for ColourScale and linkColor needed to have a hash prior to the hexidecimal code:

```
ColourScale <- 'd3.scaleOrdinal().domain(["First", "Second", "Both","Neither"]).range(["#7554A3", "#96C93C", "#ECB602","#d3d3d3"]);'

...
...
...

if (linkColor_both[l]) {
  linkColor[l] = "#ECB602"
} else if (linkColor_first[l]) {
  linkColor[l] = "#7554A3"
} else if (linkColor_second[l]) {
  linkColor[l] = "#96C93C"
} else {
  linkColor[l] = "lightgrey"
}
```

Not sure why Safari accepted the colors without the hash, but Chrome and Firefox now accept the node colors and edge colors when the hash is included.